# Determining if no rows are returned from a prepared statment

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm implementing prepared statements on my already working mysqli queries. I'm having trouble with a line `if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)` as it's now a string instead of a mysqli_result.

```
if($nameAvailableStmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'SELECT name FROM usetbl1 WHERE name=? LIMIT 1'))
{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($nameAvailableStmt, "s", $_POST['dangerous']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($nameAvailableStmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($nameAvailableStmt, $result);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($nameAvailableStmt);
}
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
```

Comment: $result should be $nameAvailableStmt

Comment: it should bd `mysqli_num_rows($nameAvaialbleStmt)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
mysqli_stmt_store_result($nameAvailableStmt);
if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($nameAvailableStmt) == 0)
```

See the [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)

Comment: Yes, it means that. `$result` will just contain the name that you were searching for.

Comment: It still gives me the same error, I'll keep trying and clear the cache.

Comment: You need to call mysqli_stmt_store_result() first.

Comment: Same ` Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given `

Comment: Use `mysqli_stmt_num_rows()`. `mysqli_num_rows()` is for when you're not using prepared statements.

Comment: thanks I think that does it, now the only problem is the statement is always true.

Comment: For some reason I had to add `mysqli_stmt_store_result($nameAvailableStmt)` for it to work

Comment: I know, I added that to the answer yesterday.