# What's the difference between the mysqli functions bind_result, store_result and fetch?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm running into problems knowing when and what to call after `mysqli_stmt_execute`
How do you know when to call

1. mysqli_stmt_bind_result
2. mysqli_stmt_store_result
3. mysqli_stmt_fetch

Comment: short answer: store_result stores it, bind_result organizes it, fetch pulls it out so it can be used for output http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`mysqli_stmt_bind_result()` tells mysqli which variable you want to be populate when you fetch a row, but it doesn't `fetch()` anything yet.  This is necessary to call once, before you call fetch.

`mysqli_stmt_store_result()` sets an optional behavior so that the client downloads all rows when you `fetch()` the first row, and caches the whole result set in the client (i.e. PHP).  Subsequent `fetch()` calls will simply iterate over this client-cached result set.  But setting this option itself does not cause a fetch() yet either.  This function is totally optional.

`mysqli_stmt_fetch()` returns the next row in the result set, and causes it to be stored in a bound variable. You must call this function in a loop, for each row of the result set. That is, until the fetch returns false.

Comment: If I know the query will return at most 1 row then `mysqli_stmt_store_result()` is pointless, right?

Comment: Right; the alternative is `mysqli_use_result()`, which fetches one row at a time from the MySQL server at the time you call fetch.  If your query result is known to have only one row, there's no difference between these two strategies.

Comment: Wait something's not right; [as discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054131/determining-if-no-rows-are-returned-from-a-prepared-statment) `mysqli_stmt_num_rows()` doesn't work unless `mysqli_stmt_store_result()` had been called. Why is this? Is it because PHP "isn't smart enough" to download the rest of the rows so it can't count them all where as calling `mysqli_stmt_store_result()` downloads all rows?

Comment: @Celeritas, it's not going to download all rows if you didn't say it's okay to do so, by calling store_result.  The client can't know if there's a billion rows in the result set.  And the client can't calculate num_rows until it downloads all rows.  This is true in the underlying C client API, not only in PHP.

Answer (score 5):

The process of querying an SQL database contains these steps:

- sending of the query to the SQL server
- the SQL server parsing the query and gathering the requested result set
- transferring of the found result set data from the SQL server to PHP
- putting the data into PHP variables somehow so the script can work with them

The functions you ask about have these roles in this process:

- store: transfer all rows immediately from the MySQL database into PHP's memory; typically has no practical effect and is done automatically at some point anyway
- bind: bind variables, so that when you call `fetch()` those variables contain result data; i.e. tell PHP which variables it should put the result into
- fetch: "read" a row from the result set and store it in the variables you previously bound; if the data is not in PHP's memory yet it will be transferred from the SQL server at this point